# Getting error when pushing notification after deploy on linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, deployment, notifications

I'm getting error when sending notification using **rpush** gem after deploying on linux server while all notification data is saved into table.

On my local i was pushing notification by **rpush push** command but on linux this command is not found so please help me to sort out this problem.

Comment: Please post the error message, as error messages actually tell you what has gone wrong.

Comment: -bash: rpush: command not found

Answer (score 0):

`rpush` is not being found in your path (an environment variable which contains the file paths for all executable files). You can confirm this with the `which` command.

`which rpush`

The fact it returns nothing tells you it is not in your path. If it was in your path it will return the file path of the executable file that runs when you enter the command into the terminal.

Prior to adding it to your path, just check it is actually installed.

You can add it to the path by opening `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` (where the squiggle ~ is your home directory) and entering:

`export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/rpush/executable`

Then reload your terminal or type `source ~/.profile` for example.

For some documentation on paths there is the [Linux Info site](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html), and for Bash profiles you can check out [this page](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/6.3/postlfs/profile.html).